# Sinusoidal FM modulation of a sqarewave carrier in gnu-octave

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, octave

I have used the following code in octave to implement frequency modulation with sinusoidal message and square wave carrier.

```
%script to make a squarewave carrier modulated with a sinusoidal message
fmsg=1; %Message signal frequency. 1 Hz
fc=10;  %carrier frequency, 10 Hz
Fs=200; %sampling frequency, 200 Hz
t=[0:1/Fs:3/fmsg]; %Time duaration defined


%The message signal
x=2.*sin(2*pi*fmsg*t);
subplot(3,1,1); plot(t,x); title('Message')

%The carrier signal
y=5.*square(2*pi*fc*t);
subplot(3,1,2);plot(t,y); title('Carrier')

%steps for FM modulation
x_max=max(x);
x_modulating=x./x_max;  %x_modulating is normalized to unity
fdev=x_modulating*fc/2;     %finding frequency deviation corresponding to a maximum of       50% deviation from the carrier frequency
fc=fc*ones(size(t));    %making the size of fc and fdev the same so that they can be added
z=5.*square(2*pi*((fc+fdev).*t));   %Generating FM signal
subplot(3,1,3);plot(t,z);title('FM');
print('fm.png');
```

But the resultant FM waveform has a frequency which is not proportional to the message signal amplitude. What could be the reason. How could it be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation#Theory), the phase of an FM signal is proportional to the *integral* of the instantaneous frequency, which is not quite the same thing as multiplying the instantaneous frequency with the running time.

A simple phase integration can be implemented by modifying the last part of the code you provided to something such as:

```
% fc = fc*one(size(t)); % will use scalar fc for all i below
phase = 0;
for i=1:size(t,2)
  z(i) = 5.*square(phase);
  phase = mod(phase + 2*pi*(fc+fdev(i))/Fs, 2*pi);
endfor
```

Note that the since modulating signal varies within the sampling period, you could get a slightly more accurate integration with a trapezoid-rule integrator, but the above should be sufficient for most applications.

Comment: The effect of integration in discrete time can also be implemented using **cumsum()** function in communication package of octave.
Hence the step for implementing frequency modulation in the question can be replaced with the following line of code.

`z = square (2*pi*fc.*t + 2*pi*cumsum(fdev)/Fs);`